# When to use Mockito.verify()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I write jUnit test cases for 3 purposes:

1. To ensure that my code satisfies all of the required functionality, under all (or most of) the input combinations/values.
2. To ensure that I can change the implementation, and rely on JUnit test cases to tell me that all my functionality is still satisfied.
3. As a documentation of all the use cases my code handles, and act as a spec for refactoring - should the code ever need to be rewritten. (Refactor the code, and if my jUnit tests fail - you probably missed some use case).

I do not understand why or when `Mockito.verify()` should be used. When I see `verify()` being called, it is telling me that my jUnit is becoming aware of the implementation. (Thus changing my implementation would break my jUnits, even though my functionality was unaffected).

I'm looking for:

1. What should be the guidelines for appropriate usage of `Mockito.verify()`?
2. Is it fundamentally correct for jUnits to be aware of, or tightly coupled to, the implementation of the class under test?

Comment: I try to stay away from using verify() as much as I can, for the very same reason you exposed (i don't want my unit test to become aware of the implementation), but there a is case when I have no choice - stubbed void-methods. Generally speaking as they  do not return anything they do not contribute to your 'actual' output; but still, you need to know that it was called.
But I agree with you it makes no sense to use verify to verify execution flow.

Answer (score 82):

If the contract of class A includes the fact that it calls method B of an object of type C, then you should test this by making a mock of type C, and verifying that method B has been called.

This implies that the contract of class A has sufficient detail that it talks about type C (which might be an interface or a class).  So yes, we're talking about a level of specification that goes beyond just "system requirements", and goes some way to describing implementation.

This is normal for unit tests.  When you are unit testing, you want to ensure that each unit is doing the "right thing", and that will usually include its interactions with other units.  "Units" here might mean classes, or larger subsets of your application.

**Update:**

I feel that this doesn't apply just to verification, but to stubbing as well.  As soon as you stub a method of a collaborator class, your unit test has become, in some sense, dependent on implementation.  It's kind of in the nature of unit tests to be so.  Since Mockito is as much about stubbing as it is about verification, the fact that you're using Mockito at all implies that you're going to run across this kind of dependency.

In my experience, if I change the implementation of a class, I often have to change the implementation of its unit tests to match.  Typically, though, I won't have to change the inventory of what unit tests there **are** for the class; unless of course, the reason for the change was the existence of a condition that I failed to test earlier.

So this is what unit tests are about.  A test that doesn't suffer from this kind of dependency on the way collaborator classes are used is really a sub-system test or an integration test.  Of course, these are frequently written with JUnit too, and frequently involve the use of mocking.  In my opinion, "JUnit" is a terrible name, for a product that lets us produce all different types of test.

Comment: Thanks, David. 

After scanning through some code sets, this seems like a common practice - but for me, this defeats the purpose of creating unit tests, and just adds the overhead of maintaining them for very little value. 

I do understand why mocks are required, and why the dependencies for executing the test needs to be setup. But verifying that method dependencyA.XYZ() is executed makes the tests very brittle, in my opinion.

Comment: @Russell Even if "type C" is an interface for a wrapper around a library, or around some distinct subsystem of your application?

Comment: I would'nt say it is completly useless to ensure some sub system or service was invoked-just that there should be some guidelines around it(formulating them was what I wanted to do). 
For ex: (I'm probably over-simplying it) Say,I'm using StrUtil.equals() in my code,and decide to switch to StrUtil.equalsIgnoreCase() in the implementation.If jUnit had verify(StrUtil.equals), my test could fail though implementation is accurate. This verify call,IMO,is bad practice though it is for libraries/sub-systems. On the other hand, using verify to ensure a call to closeDbConn might be a valid usecase.

Comment: I understand you and agree with you completely. But I also feel that writing the guidelines that you describe could expand into writing an entire TDD or BDD textbook. To take your example, calling `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` would never be something that was specified in the requirements of a class, so would never have a unit test per se. However, "closing the DB connection when done" (whatever this means in terms of implementation) may well be a requirement of a class, even though it's not a "business requirement". For me, this comes down to the relationship between the contract ...

Comment: ... of a class as expressed in its business requirements, and the set of test methods that unit test that class.  Defining this relationship would be an important topic in any book on TDD or BDD.  Whereas someone in the Mockito team could write a post on this topic for their wiki, I don't see how it would differ from lots of other available literature.  If you see how it might differ, let me know, and maybe we can work on it together.

Comment: @DavidWallace thanks for your answer, I am a bit confused, lets say in my mockedClass I have two methods called m1 and m2. m1 is required to call m2. should I use verify method to verify that m1 is calling m2? as following verify(myMockedClass).m2(); ?

Comment: @Jack is `m1` _really_ required to call `m2`?  Or is it required to do something that happens to be identical to what `m2` does?  The latter seems far more likely to me - and if this is the case, you should simply test that `m1` does the right thing, not that it calls `m2`.

Comment: @DavidWallace actually the code is like m1(){ …. int a = m2();  ….}

Answer (score 66):

David's answer is of course correct but doesn't quite explain why you would want this.

Basically, when unit testing you are testing a unit of functionality in isolation. You test whether the input produces the expected output. Sometimes, you have to test side effects as well. In a nutshell, verify allows you to do that.

For example you have bit of business logic that is supposed to store things using a DAO. You could do this using an integration test that instantiates the DAO, hooks it up to the business logic and then pokes around in the database to see if the expected stuff got stored. That's not a unit test any more.

Or, you could mock the DAO and verify that it gets called in the way you expect. With mockito you can verify that something is called, how often it is called, and even use matchers on the parameters to ensure it gets called in a particular way.

The flip side of unit testing like this is indeed that you are tying the tests to the implementation which makes refactoring a bit harder. On the other hand, a good design smell is the amount of code it takes to exercise it properly. If your tests need to be very long, probably something is wrong with the design. So code with a lot of side effects/complex interactions that need to be tested is probably not a good thing to have.

Answer (score 32):

This is great question!
I think the root cause of it is the following, we are using JUnit not only for unit testing. So the question should be splited up:

- Should I use Mockito.verify() in my *integration* (or any other higher-than-unit testing) testing?
- Should I use Mockito.verify() in my **black-box** unit-testing?
- Should I use Mockito.verify() in my **white-box** unit-testing?

so if we will ignore higher-than-unit testing, the question can be rephrased "*Using **white-box** unit-testing with Mockito.verify() creates great couple between unit test and my could implementation, can I make some **"grey-box"** unit-testing and what rules of thumb I should use for this*".

Now, let's go through all of this step-by-step.

*- Should I use Mockito.verify() in my *integration* (or any other higher-than-unit testing) testing?*
I think the answer is clearly no, moreover you shouldn't use mocks for this. Your test should be as close to real application as possible. You are testing complete use case, not isolated part of the application.

****black-box*** vs **white-box** unit-testing*
If you are using **black-box** approach what is you really doing, you supply (all equivalence classes) input, a *state*, and tests that you will receive expected output. In this approach using of mocks in general is justifies (you just mimic that they are doing the right thing; you don't want to test them), but calling Mockito.verify() is superfluous.

If you are using **white-box** approach what is you really doing, you're testing the *behaviour* of your unit. In this approach calling to Mockito.verify() is essential, you should verify that your unit behaves as you're expecting to.

**rules of thumbs for grey-box-testing** 
The problem with white-box testing is it creates a high coupling. One possible solution is to do grey-box-testing, not white-box-testing. This is sort of combination of black&white box testing. You are really testing the *behaviour* of your unit like in white-box testing, but in general you make it implementation-agnostic *when possible*. When it is possible, you will just make a check like in black-box case, just asserts that output is what is your expected to be.  So, the essence of your question is when it is possible.

This is really hard. I don't have a good example, but I can give you to examples. In the case that was mentioned above with equals() vs equalsIgnoreCase() you shouldn't call Mockito.verify(), just assert the output. If you couldn't do it, break down your code to the smaller unit, until you can do it. On the other hand, suppose you have some @Service and you are writting @Web-Service that is essentially wrapper upon your @Service - it delegates all calls to the @Service (and making some extra error handling). In this case calling to Mockito.verify() is essential, you shouldn't duplicate all of your checks that you did for the @Serive, verifying that you're calling to @Service with correct parammeter list is sufficient.

Comment: Grey box testing is a bit of a pitfall. I tend to restrict it to things like DAOs. I've been on some projects with extremely slow builds because of an abundance of grey box tests, a near complete lack of unit tests and way too many blackbox tests to compensate for the lack of trust in what the greybox tests were supposedly testing.

Comment: To me this is the best available answer since it answers when to use Mockito.when() in a variety of situations. Well done.

Answer (score 8):

I must say, that you are absolutely right from a classical approach's point of view:

- If you first *create (or change) business logic* of your application and then *cover it with (adopt) tests* (*Test-Last approach*), then it will be very painful and dangerous to let tests know anything about how your software works, other than checking inputs and outputs.
- If you are practicing a [*Test-Driven approach*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), then your tests are the [first to be written, to be changed and to reflect the use cases](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Red-Green-Refactor.html) of your software's functionality. **The implementation depends on tests.** That sometimes mean, that you want your software to be implemented in some particular way, e.g. rely on some other component's method or even call it a particular amount of times. That is where [Mockito.verify()](http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify) comes in handy!

It is important to remember, that there are no universal tools. The type of software, it's size, company goals and market situation, team skills and many other things influence the decision on which approach to use at your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases when people don't like using Mockito.verify, it is because it is used to verify everything that the tested unit is doing and that means you will need to adapt your test if anything changes in it.
But, I don't think that is a problem. If you want to be able to change what a method does without the need to change it's test, that basically means you want to write tests which don't test everything your method is doing, because you don't want it to test your changes. And that is the wrong way of thinking.

What really is a problem, is if you can modify what your method does and a unit test which is supposed to cover the functionality entirely doesn't fail. That would mean that whatever the intention of your change is, the result of your change isn't covered by the test.

Because of that, I prefer to mock as much as possible: also mock your data objects. When doing that you can not only use verify to check that the correct methods of other classes are called, but also that the data being passed is collected via the correct methods of those data objects. And to make it complete, you should test the order in which calls occur.
Example: if you modify a db entity object and then save it using a repository, it is not enough to verify that   the setters of the object are called with the correct data and that the save method of the repository is called. If they are called in the wrong order, your method still doesn't do what it should do.
So, I don't use Mockito.verify but I create an inOrder object with all mocks and use inOrder.verify instead. And if you want to make it complete, you should also call Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions at the end and pass it all the mocks. Otherwise someone can add new functionality/behavior without testing it, which would mean after while your coverage statistics can be 100% and still you are piling up code which isn't asserted or verified.

Answer (score 0):

As some people said

1. Sometimes you don't have a direct output on which you can assert
2. Sometimes you just need to confirm that your tested method is sending the correct indirect outputs to its collaborators (which you are mocking).

Regarding your concern about breaking your tests when refactoring, that is somewhat expected when using mocks/stubs/spies. I mean that by definition and not regarding a specific implementation such as Mockito. 
But you could think in this way - if you need to do a refactoring that would create major changes on the way your method works, it is a good idea to do it on a TDD approach, meaning you can change your test **first** to define the new behavior (that will fail the test), and **then** do the changes and get the test passed again.