# Doubts with mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have a doubt with Mockito.
I would want to test this simple class:

```
public class MyClass{
    private UserService userService;
    public void deleteUser(){
       userService.getAdminUser(1);
       userService.deleteUser(0);
    }
}
```

I wrote this simple test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class MyClassTest {
       @MockitoAnnotations.Mock
       private UserService userService;

        @Test
        public void test(){
           MyClass  myClass=new MyClass();
           myClass.userService=userService;
           myClass.deleteUser();
        }
    }
```

This test run with no errors.
I await that it didn't compile because there isn't any call to userService method..

Comment: \@MockitoAnnotations.Mock is deprecated, just use \@Mock

Comment: Anyone know how to escape @ signs in comments so SO doesn't think I'm directing my comment to someone?

Comment: @TomMcIntyre If you use backticks around a word or expression, it will  be inlined and formatted, e.g. `@Mock`, see the help link when writing a comment.

Comment: What would the purpose of such a test be?  What are you hoping to verify?

Answer (score 3):

Mocks created by Mockito are "smart". They don't do anything when a void method is called. They return null when a method returning an object is called. They return an empty collection when a method returning a collection is called.

If you want to verify that `getAdminUser()` and `deleteUser()` have been called, use `Mockito.verify()`.

These two things are explained in the [Mockito documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html), points 1 and 2. In particular:

> By default, for all methods that return value, mock returns null, an empty collection or appropriate primitive/primitive wrapper value (e.g: 0, false, ... for int/Integer, boolean/Boolean, ...).

Answer (score 0):

you have not added any check to see if userService is used in any way. Adding a verify will do that for you: [When to use Mockito.verify()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539365/when-to-use-mockito-verify)

I would advice you to read up on how Mockito works in tests, I think you have jumped past some of the fundamentals when it comes to learning the design and how method calls to the mock is treated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would test it with a different set of methods which invokes no annotations. Note that this is TestNG, but adapting it to JUnit 4+ is easy:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public final class Test
{
    private UserService userService;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void init()
    {
        userService = mock(UserService.class);
    }

    @Test
    {
         final MyClass  myClass = new MyClass();
         myClass.userService = userService;
         myClass.deleteUser();
         verify(userService, times(1)).getAdminUser(1);
         verify(userService, times(1)).deleteUser(0);
    }
}
```

Note that there is a one-argument only `verify()` variant, which is exactly equivalent to having `times(1)` as the second argument. There is also `never()`.

If for instance you wanted to test that the `.deleteUser()` method was not called with any argument, you'd do:

```
verify(userService, never()).deleteUser(anyInt());
```